# Import Jquery into codeigniter 2.X

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to import Jquery into codeigniter 2.X without exit. I put the link to the library and I saw in the debugger that it load it without errors, but , when I use the Docuemtn ready function it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a").click(function() {
                alert("Hello world!");
            });
        });

    </script>
    <title>Hardware Deal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='header'>
        <h1> Hardware deal </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='body'>
        <form action='' method = 'post'>
            Customer Name:<input type='text' name='Cname' id='CName'/><br>
            Adress:<input type='text' name='CAddress'/><br>
            Existing Customer? yes<input type='radio' name='existing' value='yes'> no<input type='radio' name='existing' value='no'><br>

            Printer Contition: <select name='PCondition'/>
                                <option value=''></option>
                                <option value='New Press'>New Press</option>
                                <option value='Second Hand'>Second Hand</option>
                                </select>
        </form>
         <a href="">Link</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `http:` from the source of the first script.  Change the first script tag to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The type of the second script tag is wrong.  Change the second script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });
</script>
```